# I'd like to create a form with several checkboxes, but I'm not sure how to structure the tables to capture the checked items

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

This is essentially a form for a day of tracking tasks. Any number of these boxes can be checked, and I'd like the results saved as results for that day. So Monday would have a form, as would Tuesday etc. Would each task have to have its own field in the table? So essentially 27 fields with the corresponding set to yes/no and then a date field to associate all checked tasks with a single date (the day they were checked off as completed)?

Something seems wrong about this approach but I'm new to databases and cannot think of another way.

Thank you.[final form should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj00G.jpg)

Comment: Question is about db design (and too broad), not programming and not really appropriate to SO.

Comment: Asking if I need a field for each checkboxed item is too broad?  There's definitely database design sections on SO, so I'm confused about the programming comment.

Comment: Since there is no code to analyze, advice would be in the realm of opinion. Review https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Suggest you research database normalization as what you describe does not appear to meet the standards of normalization.

Comment: You can throw the 27 variables into 1 table with the date and even use most access features so go ahead and do that for the practice.  You also don't need a separate form for the day of the week as the date already contains that information (see weekday function).  Normalization makes storage and retrieval more complicated but gives you benefits that are way worth the price.  First data is stored more efficiently lowering storage space costs and speeding up retrieval.  More importantly it is far easier to expand and upgrade a normalized database.

Comment: @mazoula Thanks for your input.  In terms of putting the 27 tasks into one table, would I enter each task as its own field, set to Yes/No, amounting to 27 fields?  Or would I put all 27 tasks into one field, with an adjacent done field, basically amounting to two fields with 27 records?  Somehow the first option seems to violate normalization rules as its essentially setting up fields to be "task 1, task 2, task 3" etc but I can't figure out another way. Then again, the 27 tasks equate to one record, so there's that to consider as well.

Comment: 27 separate yes/no one for each task with a date field.  then base the forms off that.  then the unit of observation is a day and each yes/no is whether you did that task on that day.  date can be the primary key or let access add an autonumber field.

Comment: @mazoula thanks for the advice!  Is that breaking normalization rules though?  I mean not that it matters, but is this an "acceptable" way to approach this?  Is having the 27 tasks as one record the same as "phone number 1, phone number 2" faux pas?

Comment: yes, this is an acceptable way for a small project that is not going to grow much.  You will have to read up on why we normalize as a comment is to brief a space.  If you are doing this project to learn just do a normal version as well, I didn't include a normalized version only because there was no space in a comment for the picture.